# Reinstall kubuntu while keeping configuration and data

Tags: kubuntu, home-directory, reinstall, data-loss

I'm facing constant issues with my system and have decided to do a reinstall while keeping /home intact, but the guide I find are either old guides or not the information I'm looking.

I'm currently using Kubuntu 20.4. I do not have a separate /home partition. I basically want to reinstall the system as if it was fresh, but still keep the data in /home, the configurations and apps. My question is, if I reinstall Kubuntu using a liveusb, and un-check the format partition, does it leave /home untouched, meaning, when I boot the OS will it have all the apps, system config. and data?  Also wondering, when I reinstall, does it revert all items in [/] back to the original state, or reverts them to factory while keeping files I have installed as well?

I tried reinstalling kubuntu with format and moving old /home to the new one and faced numerous issues like KDE being unable to read the configurations etc. Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: You can reinstall without choosing "Erase Disk" and it does what you're asking. However if you already tried copying your home to a clean install, and there were problems, reinstalling over your existing install is almost certainly not going to work either.  Your problem(s) may actually exist within your home folder- lots of configs are stored there.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for the reply. In the end I made 2 partitions (A, B). I moved /home to partition B and reinstalled/format partition A and assigned B as /home directory. After a few tweaks here and there my system is working fine. Before that I tried installing Fedora 36(coming from kubuntu 20.4) and copy my /home folder to it and it was a mess. Everything was broken. Decided to stay in Kubuntu 20.4. Thank you for your help. The bad apples were in face in / directory as now everything is working again. Restoring old /home did not however reinstall my apps.